# JMeter - saving results + configuring "graph results" time span

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter and have 2 questions (I have read the FAQ + Wiki etc):

1. I use the [Graph Results listener](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results). It seems to have a fixed span, e.g. 2 hours (just guessing - this is not indicated anywhere AFAIK), after which it wraps around and starts drawing on same canvas from the left again. Hence after a long weekend run it only shows the results of last 2 hours. Can I configure that span or other properties (beyond the check boxes I see on the Graph Results listener itself)?
2. Can I save the results of a run and later open them? I know I can save the test plan or parts of it. I am unclear if I can save separately just the test results data, and later open them and perform comparisons etc. And furthermore can I open them with different listeners even if they weren't part of original test (i.e. I think of the test as accumulating data, and later on I want to view and interpret the data using different "viewers").

Thanks,

-- Shaul

Comment: there is no limit of 2 hours but after a number of point it restart at the beginning of the canvas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know about 1. Regarding 2: listeners typically have a configuration field for "Write All Data to a File", which lets you specify the file name. You can use the [Simple Data Writer](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component%5Freference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to store results efficiently for later analysis.

You can load results from a previous test into a visualizer by choosing "Write All Data to a File" and browsing for the file you wish to load. Somewhat counterintuitively, selecting a file for writing also loads that file into the visualizer and displays the results. Just make sure you don't run the test again while that file is selected, otherwise you will lose your saved test data. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Does the simple data writer save only the timing data (what I want) or also the responses (I don't need that, and could be lots of data). Also wondering if the times reported by the various listeners are on the server or client. I.e. in my case running a JDBC query test is it just the time to process the query in the DB or also the time to format the results and send them to the client?

-- Shaul

Comment: Oh, I see I can configure the data that is saved. Got it. But when I click "Browse" it looks like it is trying to open an existing  XXX.jtl file, not create a new one (i.e. if I give a new name and click "open" it gives me a "Error loading results file - file not found" message)?

Where am I supposed to specify  a new results file? Thanks...

Comment: @Shaul: may you find it already, but you can just type in that open file dialog. Jmeter functions are really counter-intuitive

Answer (score 8):

Well, I later found a JMeter group that was [discussing the issue raised in my first question](http://www.nabble.com/Graph-Results-overlap-td23477206.html#a23477206), and B.Ramann gave me an excellent suggestion to use instead a better graph found [here](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/better-jmeter-graphs/).

-- Shaul